# Как реализовать подгрузку без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

У меня на сайте есть меню на которой выводиться несколько ссылок. Одна из них ведет на страницу с сообщениями и в тексте этой ссылки написано например `Сообщения(2)`.
Так вот- эта "2" подгружается из базы и при новом сообщении переменная меняется на "3", но это можно увидеть только лишь обновив страницу.
Вопрос: как сделать чтобы не обновляя страницу обновлялось это значение. Самый яркий пример это многим известный сайт ВКонтакте.

Comment: AJAX+DOM+JavaScript+window.setTimeout

Comment: я не понял)) можно поподробней?

Answer (score 1):

Товарищи, Аякс - для передачи асинхронного запроса, а то что вы предлагаете делать с помощью аякс, нужно делать через COMET, гугл вам в руки и вперед.

Answer (score 0):

Раз в пару секунд (но не раньше, чем пришел предидущий ответ) отправляйте серверу AJAX-запрос. Результат вписывайте на странице, где нужно

Answer (score 0):

Если вам требуется динамически вытащить с сервера какую-либо информацию, то вам в помощь ТОЛЬКО AJAX. К сожалению, других технологий для динамического взаимодействия с сервером нет.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9vnLdun/), Я думаю Вы разберетесь. Пример каждые 3 секунды обновляет данные в div, а дальше уже используйте свой запросы ajax.

```
^
```